# Is it bad practice to hide memory allocations in functions?

Tags: c, malloc

Should I expect the user to provide a memory chunk of sufficient size, say, for copying a file into a buffer? Or should I allocate the memory myself, and expect the user to free it when they're done? For example, the function `strdup()` allocates memory itself, but the function `fread()` expects only a buffer of sufficient size.

Comment: It's often better if the user of the function can control the allocation.

Comment: The rule is simple: "What you allocate, you must deallocate when it's not meant to be used anymore".

Comment: I wouldn't consider it bad practice, but I prefer the caller to supply the callee with what it needs, if for no other reason than the symmetry of equal numbers of `malloc`s and `free`s in your code. [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) is another function that will happily allocate memory for you internally. Good documentation is the most important thing.

Comment: Either design works -- and both have their merits on occasion.  The most crucial thing is that the documentation tells people exactly what to do to free the memory returned, or provide a function that frees the memory.  For example, if you're building a tree structure, have the tree builder functions allocate the memory, but also have a function to release all the memory.  Given a choice, make it flexible -- let the user control the memory allocation. But it isn't always sensible (`strdup()` is fine; so is `fread()`, so is POSIX `getline()` -- they're different, but the documentation says so).

Comment: Note that standard I/O `FILE *` typically does allocate memory for you; you don't have to worry about it, though, because the `fclose()` releases it.  It is a reason you should ensure you close what you open, though.

Comment: "bad practice to **hide** memory allocations in functions?" Yes. "bad practice to **clearly code and document** memory allocations in functions?" No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends - I've seen C APIs use all kind of patterns for this, such as:

- functions that require the buffer and buffer size to be provided, and return the required size (so that you can adjust the buffer size if it was truncated); many of these allow passing `NULL` as a buffer if you are just asking how big the buffer should be; this allows the caller to use an existing buffer or to allocate an appropriately sized one, although with two calls;
- separate functions to obtain needed size and to fill the buffer; same as above, but with a clearer interface;
- functions that require buffer and buffer size, but can allocate the buffer themselves if `NULL` is passed as buffer; maximum flexibility and terseness, but the function signature can get confusing;
- functions that just return a newly allocated string; simple to use and avoids bugs arising from unguarded truncation, but inflexible if performance is a concern; also, requires the caller to remember to free the returned value, which is avoided in the cases above if using a stack-allocated buffer;
- functions that return a pointer to a static buffer, and then the caller is responsible to do whatever with it; extremely easy to use, extremely easy to misuse; requires care in case of multithreading (needs thread local storage) and if reentrancy is a concern.

The last one is generally a bad idea - it poses problems with reentrancy and thread safety; the one before it can be used but may pose efficiency problems - I generally don't want to waste time in allocations if I have already a buffer big enough. All the others are generally pretty much OK.

But besides the specifics of the interface, the most important point if you allocate stuff and/or return pointers is to clearly document who owns the pointed memory - is it a static object in your library? Is it a pointer to some internal of an object provided by the caller? Is it dynamically allocated stuff? Is the caller responsible for freeing it? Is it just the buffer that was provided as argument?

Most importantly, in case you allocated stuff, always specify how to deallocate it; notice that, if you are building a library that may be compiled as a dll/so, it's a good idea to provide your own deallocation function (even if it's just a wrapper around `free`) to avoid mismatches between different versions of the C runtime running in the same process. Also, it avoids tying your code to the C library allocator - today it may be fine, tomorrow it may turn out that using a custom allocator may be a better idea.

Comment: That is a good point about libs.  It can be very confusing if the developer does not realize that the library is running a different instance of memory manager/heap:(

Answer (score 3):

> Is it bad practice to hide memory allocations in functions?

Sometimes.

An answer to show when code can be abused to detail one of the pitfalls of allowing a function total freedom in memory allocation.

---

A classic case occurs when the function itself determines the size needed, so the calling code lacks the information needed to to provide the memory buffer beforehand.

This is the case with [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) where the stream content throttles the size of the allocation.  The problem with this, especially when the stream is `stdin`, is that the control over memory allocation is given to external sources and not limited by the calling code - the program.  External input may overwhelm memory space - a hack.

With a modified function, such as `ssize_t getline_limit(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream, size_t limit);`, the function could still provide a right-size allocation, yet still prevent a hacker abuse.

```
#define LIMIT 1000000
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t nread;

while ((nread = getline_limit(&line, &len, stdin, LIMIT)) != -1) {
```

---

An example where this is not an issue would be an allocation with a well bounded use.

```
// Convert `double` to its decimal character representation allocating a right-size buffer
// At worst a few thousand characters
char *double_to_string_exact_alloc(int x)
```

---

Functions that perform memory allocation need some level of control to prevent unlimited memory allocation either with a specific parameter or by nature of the task.

Answer (score 2):

C library functions refrain from returning allocated memory. That's at least part of the reason why strdup is not part of the standard library, along with a popular scanf extension for reading C strings of unlimited length.

Your library could choose either way. Using pre-allocated buffers is more flexible, because it lets users pass you statically allocated buffers. This flexibility comes at a cost, because user's code becomes more verbose.

If you choose to allocate memory for a custom struct dynamically, it is a good idea to make a matching function for deallocating the struct once it becomes unnecessary to the user.